# Word problem: a system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations

Can someone please help me. I'm having a hard time answering this question.

> At a country fair, adults’ tickets sold for £5.50, senior citizens’ tickets sold for £4.00, and children’s tickets sold for £1.50. On the opening night, the number of children’s and seniors’ tickets sold was 30 more than the number of adults’ tickets sold. The number of senior citizens’ tickets sold was 6 more than four times the number of children’s tickets. Total receipts from the ticket sales were £14967. How many of each type of tickets were sold?

Comment: How far have you gotten so far? I'm asking because if you have already done the majority of the work, there's no need for us to do all that again.

Comment: I think what I did was wrong im not that confident can someone help me so that I can also use it as my basis for the other word problems that I have

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far? It could be that it's (almost) correct!

Comment: I would start by defining $A$ = number of adult tickets sold; $S$ = number of senior tickets sold and $C$ = number of children's tickets sold. With these, we can form a few equations. Have you done something similar to this?

Comment: yes i did that too

Comment: Excellent, what equations did you write?

Comment: after defining the given what i did was

Comment: C+S = A + 3=
S= 4C + 6

Comment: THEN A+ S + C = 14967

Comment: You're quite close, you just have to be a bit careful with the equations. Indeed "the number of children’s and seniors’ tickets sold was 30 more than the number of adults’ tickets sold" translates to
$$C + S = A +30
$$
and "The number of senior citizens’ tickets sold was 6 more than four times the number of children’s tickets." translates to
$$
S = 4C+6
$$
You made a small notation error here. These are two different equations and you cannot say that $A+30 = S$ or something similar.

Comment: I just mistyped it is c+s = a+30

Comment: And as for the last equation with the total ticket sales, note that the dollar amount is the sum of the ticket numbers **multiplied by their individual prices**. So just add the prices per tickets as factors and you're all set :)

Comment: then what I did is substituting th evalus

Comment: @MattiP. last question how can I identify some of the values of the missing terms by just substituting it then solving?

Comment: After putting the ticket prices in, and moving the terms around a bit, you have the equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
-A + S + C &= 30 \\
S - 4C &= 6 \\
5.50~A+4.0~S+1.50~C &= 14~967
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Do you know how to continue from here?

Comment: no im a bit confused can you help me all through out the equation?

Comment: First of all, is it clear to you how we got the equations in my last comment? Now we have a system of linear equations that we have to solve.

Comment: yes it is clear

Answer (score 3):

After putting the ticket prices in, and moving the terms around a bit, you have the equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccclr}
-A + &S &+ C &= 30 & (1)\\
&S &- 4C &= 6 &(2)\\
5.50~A&+4.0~S&+1.50~C &= 14~967 & (3)
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Now we have to use elimination to solve for the three variables. We can multiply the row (2) by $-1$ and add it to (1) to get
$$\tag{4}
-A + 5C = 24
$$
Another way to get rid of the $S$ is to multiply row (1) by 4 and then subtract row (3) from it to get
$$ \tag{5}
9.5 A -2.5C = 14~847
$$
If you multiply Equation (4) by 9.5 and add that to equation (5), you get
$$
45 C = 15~075 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad C = 335
$$
You can use this result in Equation (4) to solve for $A$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: can you finish it ill listen so that I can use this as a basis for the other pending problems that I have

Comment: Did you get the value of $A$ ? You can substitute $C=335$ to Equation (4) and then solve for $A$.

Comment: no I have not Im getting confused Im sorry

Comment: Where did you get confused? When you insert the value of $C$ to equation (4), you get
$$
-A + 5\cdot 335 = 24 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad A = 5\cdot 335 - 24 = \ldots 
$$

Comment: I'm prompting you to do a bit of work on this so that you would learn and be able to solve problems like this in the future.

Comment: i got 1651 by solving it

Comment: so the value of A = 1651

Comment: Yes, very good. That is correct. Can you now find an equation, where you could insert the value of either $A$ or $C$, to solve for the remaining variable $S$?

Comment: s-4(335) = 6 
making it s = 6 + 4(335)
s = 1346

Comment: Great, now the problem is solved :)

Comment: thank you so much for helping me you're the best!